# Absence of error while using dollar signs within displayed math

Tags: errors, displaystyle

Please consider the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ineq}[2][$0$]{#2<#1}
\[\ineq x\]
\end{document}
```

If I compile it, I get an error message, as it would be expected when one uses dollar signs within a `\[…\]` pair. The correct definition for the `\ineq` command should be

```
\newcommand{\ineq}[2][0]{#2<#1}
```

*However*, if I compile this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\abc}[3][$0$]{\begin{cases}
        #2& \text{ if } x \neq #1\\
        #3&\text{ if } x= #1
                             \end{cases}}
\begin{document}
\[\abc ab\]
\end{document}
```

then I get no error message and everything works as if I had typed `[0]` instead of `[$0$]`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside an alignment you are not in `$$ ... $$` but `$\displaystyle...$`  so single dollars just stop and start the math.

```
$\displaystyle...  $0$ ... $
```

is not as intended but not an error. It is easier to see with letters

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\abc}[3][abc$xyz0$]{\begin{cases}
        #2& \text{ if } x \neq #1\\
        #3&\text{ if } x= #1
                             \end{cases}}
\begin{document}
\[\abc ab\]
\end{document}
```